# Проблемы при импортировании со старой версии

Tags: mysql, sql

Существует очень старый сайт и при импортировании на новые версии случаются проблемы, к примеру

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 74900: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  value varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY' at line 3
```

Вот сам сам отрывок на который он ссылается

```
CREATE TABLE dogovora_types (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  key char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  value varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Что подскажете? Знаний очень мало, но сделать надо

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). Отправьте в избранное, и НИКОГДА не используйте слова из списка в качестве имён SQL-объектов. Квотирование - это для случаев, когда уже исправить не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете зарезервированное слово `key`
Вот что сказано об этом.

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word,
> you must quote it whenever you refer to it.

> The identifier quote character is the backtick ("`"):

Если идентификатор состоит из специального символа либо зарезервированного слова то вы должны заключить их в  ` (обратные кавычки)

```
CREATE TABLE dogovora_types (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `key` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  value varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!